# Logic Apps, Runlog Task Result in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

When executeing a logic app, I get a run log for each execution.

If you, in the portal, go to home->  ->Logic app run,
and in the Run History at the left hand side  chooses a run you'll get a overview like this:

[image]

When you open a task, you can get the raw output from that task
[image]

I would like to get that output from a C# program.

I know how to get access to the WorkflowRuns list, but from there I only get result of the run, and I can not, as far as I know, query each task in the run.

Hope this makes i a bit more clear.

Comment: You should read [ask].

Comment: I just know that there would be answers within minutes if the question were clear. It's not and there are none an hour later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [workflow trigger histories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowtriggerhistories/list)

You'll need to pass in the name of your trigger in `triggerName` based on your screenshot `HasEnoughOPUSSelected`.

For `workflowName` you can use the name of your logic app.

If you access the uri in the `inputsLinks` / `outputsLinks` in the response you'll be able to retrieve all the data that was passed in or out of the trigger.

Example obvuscated output.

```
{
  "value": [
      "properties": {
        "startTime": "2020-05-05T12:34:46.255558Z",
        "endTime": "2020-05-05T12:34:47.9734251Z",
        "scheduledTime": "2020-05-05T12:34:45.6500388Z",
        "status": "Succeeded",
        "code": "OK",
        "correlation": {
          "clientTrackingId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        },
        "inputsLink": {
          "uri": "https://prod-85.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/YYYY/triggers/When_a_new_email_arrives/histories/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/contents/TriggerInputs?api-version=2016-06-01&se=2020-08-05T15%3A00%3A00.0000000Z&sp=%2Ftriggers%2FWhen_a_new_email_arrives%2Fhistories%2FXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%2Fcontents%2FTriggerInputs%2Fread&sv=1.0&sig=XXXX",
          "contentVersion": "AAA",
          "contentSize": 298,
          "contentHash": {
            "algorithm": "md5",
            "value": "AAA"
          }
        },
        "outputsLink": {
          "uri": "https://prod-85.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/YYYY/triggers/When_a_new_email_arrives/histories/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/contents/TriggerOutputs?api-version=2016-06-01&se=2020-08-05T15%3A00%3A00.0000000Z&sp=%2Ftriggers%2FWhen_a_new_email_arrives%2Fhistories%2FXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%2Fcontents%2FTriggerOutputs%2Fread&sv=1.0&sig=XXXXX",
          "contentVersion": "BBB",
          "contentSize": 129395,
          "contentHash": {
            "algorithm": "md5",
            "value": "BBB"
          }
        },
        "fired": true,
        "run": {
          "name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "id": "/subscriptions/ABC/resourceGroups/ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/LogicAppName/runs/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs"
        }
      },
      "id": "/subscriptions/ABC/resourceGroups/ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/LogicAppName/triggers/When_a_new_email_arrives/histories/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/triggers/histories"
    }
  ]
}
```